# Is there another way of completing? Preferably using a string. I am trying to build a pyramid of x's without the use of the last line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a pyramid of x's without the use of the last line. How could I mimic this code by using a string
 enter code here

```js
 function breakline() {        
      for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++) { 
          document.writeln("x<br />") 
          for(j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
              document.writeln("x")
          }
      }
      document.writeln("x") 
  }
 breakline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an empty string and keep appending Xs to it in every loop.

```js
const pylength = 10;
let str = '';
for(i = 0; i < pylength; i++) { 
    str += 'x';
    document.writeln(`${str}<br/>`);
}
```